# Issue with Xmpp 5223 port (tls Starttls issue) using gloox

Tags: c++, xmpp, gloox

`XMPP Client` needs to be connected to `XMPP server` through port 5223.  `gloox library` is used to create the XMPP client.
However we used the following method to connect to the legacy Jabber SSL port, 5223.

```
############################################################################################################
ConnectionTCPClient* connA = new ConnectionTCPClient(j /*data Handler*/ , j->logInstance() , config.getXMPPServer()/*server*/, 5223 );
        connB = new ConnectionTLS(connA ,j->logInstance());
        connB->handleConnect(connA);
        connB->handleReceivedData(connA,data);
        connB->setConnectionImpl(connA);

#########################################################################################################
```

Console Output we receive is as follows:

```
#############################################################################################################



1387452820log: level: 0 area:8
This is gloox 1.0, connecting to ec2-176-34-52-210.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5223...
  1387452820log: level: 0 area:32
Connecting to ec2-176-34-52-210.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com (10.152.145.189:5223)
  1387452820log: level: 0 area:32
Connected to ec2-176-34-52-210.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com (10.152.145.189:5223)
  1387452820Sent XML: <?xml version='1.0' ?><stream:stream to='ec2-176-34-52-210.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams'  xml:lang='en' version='1.0'>

#####################################################################################################
```

BOSH is working fine for the same.

We also tried to change gloox source code to use port 5223 instead of 5222 but the result is same.

Used various different APIs to send & receive data, but the issue is not resolved.

Please help us to resolve the above issue.

However by seeing the console output & checking the same in gloox code it seems that XMPP Client
gets connected to XMPP Server but it fails in send & receive.

Please help us to resolve the above issue.

Comment: It should work like described here under "Detailed Description":
http://camaya.net/api/gloox-1.0.9/classgloox_1_1ConnectionTLS.html

Comment: Alex, Please check the code snippet above the same is already tried.